# Error in curl when submitting form with rvest in R

Tags: r, curl, cookies

I am submitting a form using the rvest package in R and keep getting this error:

```
Submitting with '<unnamed>'
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
```

I am trying to log in to a website (https://manager.greencopper.com/accounts/signin/?next=/) in order to get a cookie I need for an API call later.

I thought I could just submit the login information and then get the cookie I needed. Right now I log in via Firefox and copy the cookie to R to make the API call. Problem is that the cookie expires.

If you have any ideas how I might be able to login without getting the above error.

I am sorry that I can't provide username and password.